# How to find TRUE value from a column in R

Tags: r, filter, logical-or

I got dumb question, I have a column that has around millions of rows. I want to find if that column contains TRUE value (all the values in that column are either TRUE, FALSE, or NA. I am not very good in R so I don't want to use loop. Is there any way I can find whether this column has TRUE value or not?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sum`

```
sum(df$column_name) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if there are at least one `TRUE` in the column:

```
any(df$column_name)
```

Comment: `== TRUE` is superfluous, just `any(df$column_name)`.